# Evaluating this tricky integral - Residue theory?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

Consider the function $f(x) = \frac{ \cos( x r ) }{ x^2 + m^2 }$, where $r$ and $m$ are non-negative constants.

$\ $

I want to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) dx$. I have already checked and I know that the answer is $\frac{\pi}{2m} e^{-m r}$.

However, I'm not sure what is the best way to go about evaluating this integral. Should I use Residue theory? If so I am confused about the path I should take in evaluting...

I know $f$ can be written as:

$f(x) = \frac{\cos(xr)}{(x+im)(x-im)}$

With a little work I find that:

$2 \pi i \ \mathrm{Res}_{im}(f(x)) = \frac{\pi}{m} \cosh(mr)$

$2 \pi i \ \mathrm{Res}_{-im}(f(x)) = -\frac{\pi}{m} \cosh(mr)$

However, this doesn't seem to help me. I THINK I should just integrate in a semicircle in the complex plane, containing just one of the poles, but then I am getting the wrong answer. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your desired integral is half of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(xr)}{x^2+m^2} dx$ (by even symmetry) which is $Re \left ( \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ixr}}{x^2+m^2} dx \right )$. This integral can be calculated using a semicircular contour in the upper half plane, and you can then take the real part at the end.

Your approach probably failed because your integral cannot be directly calculated using a semicircular contour. This is because $|\cos(x+iy)|$ scales like $e^{|y|}$, so the integral over the arc does not go to zero whether you use the lower or upper half plane. But $|e^{i(x+iy)}|=e^{-y}$ which behaves nicely in the upper half plane.

A good exercise is to do the problem again with $e^{-ixr}$, taking the contour in the *lower* half plane. You should get the same answer.

Comment: Fantastic. A Quick Question: Why would switching $e^{ixr} \mapsto e^{-ixr}$ necessitate taking the contour in the $lower$ half-plane?

Comment: @Greg.Paul Because $|e^{-i(x+iy)}|=e^y$, which decays for negative $y$.